# TotalCommander rлюк или нововведение?

Tags: веб-сервер, unix

Сервер хранит файл TelegramMyBot.php
При попытке загрузить обновленную версию TotalCommander выдает сообщение
[image: Скриншот результата]

При загрузке файла на сервер самостоятельно меняет регистр на строчные буквы.
Не пойму в чем дело. 
Предыдущие несколько лет проблем с регистром не возникало.

Comment: Очевидно, дело в несовпадении регистров файлов. Не глюк

Comment: @Taypfoon, на unix-системах регистр букв имеет значение. `TelegramMyBot.php` и `telegrammybot.php` будут разными файлами. Если у вас не unix сервер, то переживать не о чем, но Total Commander правильно делает, что предупреждает.

Comment: @Taypfoon, это не глюк. Видимо FileZilla просто не настолько "умный", чтобы предупреждать о регистре букв.

Comment: @ insolor Похоже глюк ТС, в FileZilla все ок.  Раньше тотал никогда самостоятельно не изменял регистр при загрузке на сервер.

Comment: @Taypfoon, если у вас на сервере фактически файл существует с именем в нижнем регистре, и это не юникс сервер, то при заливке туда файла в кэмэл кейс, то тут два варианта - либо имя файла будет в нижнем регистре, либо в кэмэл кейс, оба варианта допустимы. Это не глюк. Если у вас юникс сервер - это это уже другой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Глюк решился удалением с ПК пары десятков программ, чисткой, переустановкой TotalCommander. Сейчас TC снова стал послушным, и не своевольничает. Благодарен всем желающим помочь.